# Using Number(data) returns NaN when data is "222"

Tags: typescript, redis

```
 redisClient.get(params, (err, data) => {
            if (connected == true) {
              // Valor PER Default
              let resp = 1
              if (data != null) {
                let value = Number(data);

              // Increment PER by 1
                               
                resp = (value + 1)
                Logger.silly(`Data= ` + data)
                Logger.silly(`Value= ` + value)
                Logger.silly(`Resp= ` + resp)
                Logger.silly(`Sending cached information ` + JSON.stringify(resp))
              }
```

The value that I get from the Redis is `"222"`

The response from logger is:

```
2021-08-16T11:38:02.063Z [undefined-module] silly: string
2021-08-16T11:38:02.066Z [undefined-module] silly: Data= "222"
2021-08-16T11:38:02.067Z [undefined-module] silly: Value= NaN
2021-08-16T11:38:02.068Z [undefined-module] silly: Resp= NaN
2021-08-16T11:38:02.069Z [undefined-module] silly: Sending cached information null
2021-08-16T11:38:02.070Z [undefined-module] silly: Write PER on Memory - NaN
```

If I use `let value = Number("222");` instead of `let value = Number(data);` it gives me the expected result.

Comment: I strongly believe that along with `222` you are receiving smth else, some non stringified number. Please add console.log for `data`

Comment: You are 100% correct, he is receiving a json encoded version of the string stored in redis, as in “222” with the quotes included (as in data === ‘“222”’). This is what makes Number() to return NaN.